# React Router with RefluxJS - Changing route Programmatically from a Store

Tags: reactjs, react-router, refluxjs

In my project I deiced to include React Router. One of my Reflux Stores need to figure out the path based on some BL and than change it. First I've tried including the `Navigation` mixin inside the Store and running `this.transitionTo("Foo");` which threw an error :  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'router' of undefined".

Someone suggested that : "`this.transitionTo` is probably accessing the router property through contexts (`this.context.router`) which do not exist in RefluxJS stores" ... Which I understand.

However there must be a way to change the router path from a Store Programmatically, or any given external JS Module.

My Code goes something like this:

```js
// routes.js
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var Router  = require('react-router');
var Route   = Router.Route; 
var App     = require('./app');
var Comp    = require('./components/comp');

var routes = (
    <Route path='/' handler={App}>      
        <Route name='Foo' path='/foo' handler={Comp}/>              
    </Route>
);

module.exports = routes;

// main.js
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var React   = require('react');
var Router  = require('react-router');
var routes  = require('./Routes');

var appElement = document.getElementsByTagName('body');

Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function(Root, state) {
    React.render(<Root params={state.params} query={state.query} />, appElement);
});

// comp.js
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var React      = require("react");
var Reflux     = require("reflux");
var Actions    = require("../actions/actions.js");
var SomeStore  = require("../stores/some-store.js");

var Comp = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        return (
            <h1>Hello World</h1>    
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Comp;

// store.js
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var SomeStore = Reflux.createStore({    

    onSomeAction: function() {
        // CHANGE ROUTER PATH HERE TO /foo
    }

});

module.exports = SomeStore;
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The router is only known by the components (React views). You need to pass the router from the context as a parameter in your action. That way, you can use this parameter to make a transition to a different route. I've been using it this way.

I have something like below in one of my action listeners in a store.

```
 _onMyAction: function (router) {
    MyApi.doSomething()
        .then(function (id) {
            // do something ...
            router.transitionTo('myNewRoute', { ref: id });
        })
        .catch(function(message) {
            // handle message
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reflux actions return a promise, so rather than doing this in the store (which IMO is wrong) you can do it in your component:

```
Actions.someAction().then(function() {
    // route transition
});
```

Whether this is completely *right*... well, I'm not sure the community has really settled on an opinion.

Comment: I personally think that the component should rather react to some store state to determine whether to transition or not. So the store updates after the action has been handled, and the component listens to store changes as usual. Based on some condition about the store data, the component transitions to a different route.

Comment: Yes, that's certainly a possibility. There used to be a guide on the react-router site about using it alongside flux and it mentioned having a routes store: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/f3a44f1bc898848d553c39e7aa53a70d0e91ec11/docs/guides/flux.md#accessing-route-and-params-from-action-creators